# Google maps location update

Tags: ios, objective-c, google-maps, routes, location

I am working on Google maps API.In this I have to draw route between two location. As soon as my location update towards route I want to change my camera position and update it on map like Google maps does to show navigation.How would I achieve this i.e, I have to update my camera position and move map along with it like navigation.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would have to update the camera position everytime you get a new coordinate from your locationManager.

To update camera with new coordinate use:

```
GMSCameraPosition *camera = [GMSCameraPosition cameraWithLatitude:newLocation.coordinate.latitude
                            longitude:newLocation.coordinate.longitude
                                 zoom:15
                              bearing:newLocation.course
                         viewingAngle:(double)viewingAngle;


[YOURMAPVIEW animateToCameraPosition:camera];
```

Then just chose a bearing angle. You may find that the newLocation.course is not quite in the right format that google maps wants. So check that. (this code is untested). Check out google maps dev docs.

Comment: I am facing new problem now, My problem is that everytime I update my location and draw shortest path my map blinks and reload data. I wanted to do like Google maps without creating blinking issue.Thanks.